# How to reset mail id number after sending mail using sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to reset the email id number after sending mail using sp_send_dbmail. Mail id numbers are incrementing every time (shown below). That is fine. But I want to reset it now.

```
Mail (Id: 9) queued.
```

Comment: Please add more clarity to your question, are you trying to reset the autoincrement value?

Comment: Question is not clear to understand. Please give us more info.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to reset the auto increment value.

Comment: I'm really curious here... why would you want to reset the mail id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All mails are stored into MSDB database.

You can see them with the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems
```

If you wish to "reset" the mails, you must delete the rows from this table and make sure no other tables references these items.

Then you have to reset the Identity

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('sysmail_mailitems', RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: I deleted the rows. But mailitem_id is still auto incrementing (changed from 9 to 10).

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, this will help you

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = (Select count(*) from tablename)
```